# Moving data in excel from a column to rows based on criteria of column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that has a column of information ie:

```
VA221
VA222
VL911
VL911 S
VL911 M
VL911 L
VL911 XL
HF2301
HF2301 S
HF2301 M
HF2301 L
VS400
VS402
```

I need to move it to a new sheet based on the items in the column I have an example below.

```
VA221    VA222    VL911    HF2301    VS400    VS402
                  VL911 S  HF2301 S
                  VL911 M  HF2301 M
                  VL911 L  HF2301 L
                  VL911 XL
```

if it was just a few I would do manually but the column will be very long. If anyone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks for looking at my problem

Rick

Comment: Please post the VBA code you have written thus far.

Answer (score 1):

This uses arrays and will be very quick:

```
Sub trnp()
Dim rngarr() As Variant
Dim oarr() As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim lg As Long

j = 1
r = 2
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    lg = .Evaluate("=LARGE(COUNTIF(" & rng.Address & ",""*"" & " & rng.Address & " & ""*""),1)")
    rngarr = rng.Value
    ReDim oarr(1 To lg, 1 To 1)
    oarr(1, 1) = rngarr(1, 1)
    For i = 2 To UBound(rngarr, 1)
        If InStr(rngarr(i, 1), Trim(Left(rngarr(i - 1, 1), 6))) > 0 Then
            oarr(r, j) = rngarr(i, 1)
            r = r + 1
        Else
            j = j + 1
            r = 2
            ReDim Preserve oarr(1 To lg, 1 To j)
            oarr(1, j) = rngarr(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    'paste back array starting in B1
    .Range("B1").Resize(UBound(oarr, 1), UBound(oarr, 2)).Value = oarr
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another VBA Macro that uses arrays and a user defined object to represent each column.  The User defined object consists of a Column Header item and then a collection of items below that.  It should be quite fast.  It makes assumptions about the data locations that should be easily modifiable at the top of the macro.

### Class Module

(rename this to cColHeaders)

---

```
Option Explicit
Private pColHeader As String
Private pColItem As String
Private pColItems As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pColItems = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Get ColHeader() As String
    ColHeader = pColHeader
End Property
Public Property Let ColHeader(Value As String)
    pColHeader = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ColItem() As String
    ColItem = pColItem
End Property
Public Property Let ColItem(Value As String)
    pColItem = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ColItems() As Collection
    Set ColItems = pColItems
End Property
Function ADDColItem(Value As String)
    ColItems.Add Value
End Function
```

---

### Regular Module

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub OrganizeByColumn()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes() As Variant
    Dim cCH As cColumnHeaders, colCH As Collection
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim lMaxItems As Long 'will be the maximum number of items in a column
    Dim V As Variant

'set source and results worksheets, ranges
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet2")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet3")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1) 'start results in wsRes A1

'Get source data == assumes in Col A starting at A1
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

'Collect and organize the data
Set colCH = New Collection
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    Set cCH = New cColumnHeaders
    With cCH
        .ColHeader = vSrc(I, 1)
        V = Split(.ColHeader)
        If UBound(V) = 0 Then
            colCH.Add cCH, .ColHeader
        Else
            .ColItem = vSrc(I, 1)
            .ADDColItem .ColItem
            colCH(V(0)).ADDColItem (.ColItem)
            J = colCH(V(0)).ColItems.Count
            lMaxItems = IIf(lMaxItems > J, lMaxItems, J)
        End If
    End With
Next I

'Create and populate results array
ReDim vRes(0 To lMaxItems, 1 To colCH.Count)

For I = 1 To colCH.Count
    With colCH(I)
        vRes(0, I) = .ColHeader
        For J = 1 To .ColItems.Count
            vRes(J, I) = .ColItems(J)
        Next J
    End With
Next I

'resize results range
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))

'write and format the results
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the maximum characters within a value before there is a space (when applicable) is 6, you can use a combination of `RTrim` and `Left` within a `While` loop.  See below:

```
Sub test()

Range("A1").Select

While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

If RTrim(Left(ActiveCell.Value, 6)) = RTrim(Left(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value, 6)) Then

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Else

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    If ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then

        ActiveCell.Cut
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Selection.End(xlUp).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Selection.End(xlUp).Select

    Else

        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Cut
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Selection.End(xlUp).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Selection.End(xlUp).Select

    End If

End If

Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Although in of itself the `.Select` is needed in places, it should be avoided as it can be volatile.  See [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I've been meaning to look into alternatives to `.Select` but haven't gotten into it.  Appreciate your help